# Why does Google Chrome makes http request for download with a higher range than the file size and how to handle it?

Tags: google-chrome, download, httprequest, httpserver, range-header

**Update**: We found out that this 1 MB kind of range was coming due to our own code only. After making a check for that, the issue got resolved.

---

We have implemented an Http server and it can serve the file with/without range. We notice that Google Chrome somehow requests higher range than the actual size. For example, for < 1 MB file, it will request exactly 1 MB (1000000) bytes as range. For more than 1 MB file size, it will request exactly 2 MB (2000000) and so on.

Eventually the subsequent requests are coming proper and catered accordingly. But for a given file, the initial requests are *purposefully* overwhelming. We tried to serve, file size instead of higher range requested, but that doesn't work.

Why does Chrome request higher range in first place and how to deal with it at the server side?

Comment: You should include the relevant request and response headers in your question. Also, could you please expand on "that doesn't work"? Why can't you simply respond with the actual number of bytes in the file?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, the issue was due to our internal coding structure. Now it's resolved. Thanks.